# If I have default value set as NULL at database, can I ignore while I adding it in c#? via using MVC4

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, model

This is the example what I had done on my program.
Currently I had set my database for accepting the datetime Allow NULL and also default value as NULL.
The datetime i set it to nullable like this:

```
System.DateTime? EntryTime
```

Then here is my code in MODEL, I do it in the model so that every function who need it can use it.

```
UserLogin newItems = db.MyItems.Create();
newItems.Id = id;
//newItems.EntryTime = null;

db.UserLogins.Add(newItems);
db.SaveChanges();
```

Even I didnt commented it, it still goes into the same error result.
when I come to update the data into database it give me "System.Data.Entity.Validation.DbEntityValidationResult" error.

I totally out of idea. Can someone help me?

**EDIT 1** I made a mistake on variable.

The only given error is System.Data.Entity.Validation.DbEntityValidationResult and no detailed information given, that's why I am totally out of idea.

Comment: please provide the error details

Comment: you don't need to set it null explicitly, it by default go null

Comment: You made LastLogin nullable but in the second block you use the EntryTime. Please make sure this field is also nullable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most ORMs won't care about the default value on the table; they care about the object - and the object *has* a value (a `null` in this case), whether or not you specify it explicitly. So *typically*, it will dutifully pass down the `null` as part of the `insert`, and the default value **will not be used**. There may be ways of overriding this in some ORMs, but personally I wouldn't count on it.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried inserting the data with insert statement?

```
INSERT INTO `table` (id) VALUES ('id_values');
```

But I guess you'll have to create a custom module for this. With my MVC application, I use the service-repository approach. Entity Framework is so **frustrating.**